# Yahoo mail prevents links in emails

Tags: email, href, sendgrid, yahoo-mail

Yahoo is removing the `href` attribute from the `<a>` elements from emails that we send for registration approval or password reset.

We are using Sendgrid web api to send mails using nodemailer-sendgrid-transport module.

After googling possible answers, I am certain that:

- We are using complete urls (starting with `https://` at the start of the url).
- We have added `target="_blank"` attribute to our `<a>` elements.
- Our emails don't go in to spam. So it's not related with disabling links in spam issue.

However these didn't solve our problem.
Is there any way to prevent yahoo from disabling links by removing `href` attribute?

Issue is not occurring when on other mail providers such as gmail etc.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the email is NOT in the SPAM folder, then adding `rel="nofollow"` to your `<a>` tags and also being sure to use the full url (including the http or https) should fix the issue.

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.myurl.com">Some Text</a>
```